# How does one upload the dSYM via fastlane to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, fastlane

Does anyone know how one uploads the dSYM via fastlane to Firebase Crashlytics

There is documentation here https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/crashlytics/#crashlytics

But I am unaware of where to get the apiToken, and this seems to be more Crashlytics without Firebase focussed

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `crashlytics` fastlane action uploads builds to Fabric's Crashlytics Beta, which is used for beta testing apps.

It sounds like you're actually looking for the [upload_symbols_to_crashlytics](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_symbols_to_crashlytics/#upload_symbols_to_crashlytics) action to upload dSYMs to Firebase Crashlytics.

Using the `upload_symbols_to_crashlytics` action you can specify the `GoogleService-Info.plist` (gsp_path) path and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the API token in your organization's settings page but you must be an admin to view it.

Documentation - https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/api-keys.html
Link to organizations page - https://www.fabric.io/settings/organizations